# returning template subclass

Tags: c++, templates, return, subclass

I have a bunch of Containers and Objects.  The containers and objects have templated subclasses.  Those templated subclasses have specialized subclasses.  In the specialized objects, I want to retrieve their containers.  Here's the code setup:

```
class Container;
template<class T> class SubContainer;

class Object
{
public:
  Object() : m_pContainer(NULL) { }

public:
  Container* GetContainer()
  {
    return m_pContainer;
  }

  void SetContainer(Container* pContainer)
  {
    m_pContainer = pContainer;
  }

private:
  Container* m_pContainer;
};

class Container
{
public:
  Container() : m_pObject(NULL) { }
  virtual ~Container() { }

public:
  void SetObject(Object* pObject)
  {
    m_pObject = pObject;
    m_pObject->SetContainer(this);
  }

protected:
  Object* m_pObject;
};

template<class T>
class SubObject : public Object
{
public:
  virtual SubContainer<SubObject>* GetSubContainer()
  {
    return dynamic_cast<SubContainer<SubObject>*>(GetContainer());
  }

  void TestMe()
  {
    SubContainer<SubObject>* pSubContainer = GetSubContainer();
    assert(pSubContainer);
  }
};

template<class T>
class SubContainer : public Container
{
};


class SubObjectInt : public SubObject<int>
{
};

class SubContainerSubObjectInt : public SubContainer<SubObject<int> > // works
//class SubContainerSubObjectInt : public SubContainer<SubObjectInt> // fails
{
};
```

Test Code:

```
SubContainerSubObjectInt* pContainer = new SubContainerSubObjectInt();
SubObjectInt* pObject = new SubObjectInt();

pContainer->SetObject(pObject);

pObject->TestMe();
```

I know that `SubContainer<SubObjectInt>` is NOT a subclass of `SubContainer<SubObject<int> >` even though `SubObjectInt` is a subclass `SubObject<int>`.

I marked the code "works" and "fails".  The line that says "fails" makes more logical sense in my code, but I can't retrieve the proper sub container that holds it.  The dynamic cast always returns NULL.

My question is: how can I retrieve the proper `SubContainer` with `GetSubContainer()` in `SubObject`?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest change to your code would be changing:

```
class SubObjectInt : public SubObject<int>
{
};
```

to

```
typedef SubObject<int> SubObjectInt;
```

The currently failing definition will now compile and return a valid pointer.

If you want particular code to be specific to SubObjectInt that is distinct from SubObject, then you could instead have:

```
template<class T>
class SubObject : public Object
{
public:
    typedef SubContainer<SubObject<T> > ContainerType;

    ContainerType* GetSubContainer()
    {
        Container* container = GetContainer();
        return dynamic_cast<ContainerType*>(container);
    }

    void TestMe()
    {
        ContainerType* pSubContainer = GetSubContainer();
        assert(pSubContainer);
    }
};
```

And then your test code looks something like:

```
SubObjectInt::ContainerType* pContainer = new SubObjectInt::ContainerType();
SubObjectInt* pObject = new SubObjectInt();

pContainer->SetObject(pObject);

pObject->TestMe();
```

EDIT: in response to first comment

well i would say you might be better off using a different design, you are intermingling inheritance and composition and templates in a way that is complicating what i think you want to achieve.

you have a container type that you want to be able to assign objects.
you have an object type that wants to know about its container.

you want container and object types that do some things the same and some things differently depending on their contents.

i would suggest something along these lines:

```
template<class T>
class ObjectStrategy
{
public:
    virtual void execute(T* object)
    {
        std::cout << "oh noes i am a default general ObjectStrategy" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
class ContainerStrategy
{
public:
    virtual void execute(T* container)
    {
        std::cout << "oops i am a default general ContainerStrategy" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
class Object;

template<class T>
class Container
{
public:
    Container() : m_pObject(0), m_strategy(new ContainerStrategy<Container<T> >()) { }
    Container(ContainerStrategy<Container<T> >* strategy_override) : m_pObject(0), m_strategy(strategy_override) { }
    ~Container() { delete m_strategy; }

    void SetObject(T* pObject)
    {
        m_pObject = pObject;
        m_pObject->SetContainer(this);
    }

    void DoContainerStuff()
    {
        m_strategy->execute(this);
    }

protected:
    T* m_pObject;
    ContainerStrategy<Container<T> >* m_strategy;
};

template<class T>
class Object
{
public:
    Object() : m_pContainer(0), m_strategy(new ObjectStrategy<Object<T> >()) { }
    Object(ObjectStrategy<Object<T> >* strategy_override) : m_pContainer(0), m_strategy(strategy_override) { }
    ~Object() { delete m_strategy; }

    Container<Object<T> >* GetContainer()
    {
        return m_pContainer;
    }

    void SetContainer(Container<Object<T> >* pContainer)
    {
        m_pContainer = pContainer;
    }

    void DoObjectStuff()
    {
        m_strategy->execute(this);
    }

    void TestMe()
    {
        DoObjectStuff();
        Container<Object<T> >* pContainer = GetContainer();
        pContainer->DoContainerStuff();
    }
protected:
    Container<Object<T> >* m_pContainer;
    ObjectStrategy<Object<T> >* m_strategy;
};

typedef Object<int> ObjectInt;

template<>
class ObjectStrategy<ObjectInt>
{
public:
    virtual void execute(ObjectInt* container)
    {
        std::cout << "omg i am a default specific strategy for ObjectInt" << std::endl;
    }
};

typedef Container<ObjectInt> ContainerObjectInt;

template<>
class ContainerStrategy<ContainerObjectInt>
{
public:
    virtual void execute(ContainerObjectInt* container)
    {
        std::cout << "pow i am a default specific strategy for ContainerObjectInt" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ObjectIntOverrideStrategy : public ObjectStrategy<ObjectInt>
{
public:
    virtual void execute(ObjectInt* object)
    {
        std::cout << "bam i am an overriding specific strategy for ObjectInt" << std::endl;
    }
};

class ContainerObjectIntOverrideStrategy : public ContainerStrategy<ContainerObjectInt>
{
public:
    virtual void execute(ContainerObjectInt* object)
    {
        std::cout << "woo i am an overriding specific strategy ContainerObjectInt" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    {   // test with default + general strategies
        typedef Object<float> ObjectFloat;
        typedef Container<ObjectFloat> ContainerObjectFloat;

        ObjectFloat* pObject = new ObjectFloat();
        ContainerObjectFloat* pContainer = new ContainerObjectFloat();

        pContainer->SetObject(pObject);

        pObject->TestMe();
    }

    {   // test with default + specific strategies
        ObjectInt* pObject = new ObjectInt;
        ContainerObjectInt* pContainer = new ContainerObjectInt;

        pContainer->SetObject(pObject);

        pObject->TestMe();
    }

    {   // test with overriding + specific strategies
        ObjectInt* pObject = new ObjectInt(new ObjectIntOverrideStrategy);
        ContainerObjectInt* pContainer = new ContainerObjectInt(new ContainerObjectIntOverrideStrategy);

        pContainer->SetObject(pObject);

        pObject->TestMe();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

common functionality of objects or containers are implemented as member functions of object or container respectively.

per-type functionality of objects or containers are implemented via composition of strategy objects, you could use a factory to produce appropriate objects and containers based on appropriate strategies.

ive put forward a fairly flexible approach (maybe too flexible), so you could ignore template specialization or inheritance on the strategy objects depending on how specific you need the behaviour.

Comment: So it's not possible to have pContainer be declared as SubContainerSubObjectInt?  Because all specialized classes do have code in them (I just made them blank to simplify the example as much as possible).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along this:

```
class SubObjectInt : public SubObject<int>
{
  public:
  typedef SubObject<int> parent;
};

class SubContainerSubObjectInt 
: virtual public SubContainer<SubObjectInt> 
, virtual public SubContainer<SubObjectInt::parent> 
{
  public:
  void SetObject(Object* pObject)
  {
    SubContainer<SubObjectInt::parent>::SetObject(pObject);
  }
};
```

To be cleaner, you should inherits privately from the SubContainer and republish the actual method you need as a public member.